# How many new users does Stack Overflow get per day?

Tags: discussion, users, statistics

There has been recently a large discussion revolving the current state of Stack Overflow at [Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251758/1026459)

As a result, I was curious how many **new** users the site receives on a daily basis but could not find the number anywhere.

The closest I could get was the estimate 1500 per day, which is 3.1 million users divided by the roughly 2000 days the site has been around.

Does anyone know, on average, what that number is now?

Comment: Your estimate assumes linear growth.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - And it definitely is not. It was the only metric I had available hence asking the question hoping for a more accurate number.

Comment: So by new users do you mean everyone that creates a registered or unregistered account?

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Everyone that has completed the openid login process to create a registered account. Do unregistered users have any site privileges?

Comment: @TravisJ On SO unregistered users are disabled from posting, but on most other sites they're pretty much the same as any 1 rep registered user.

Comment: Re: the original "negativity" issue, I don't believe that thinking in terms of *users* goes in the right direction. We should think in terms of *questions* or, even better, *answers*, as if only half of the higher-rep users who answer those questions would close them instead, we could turn the tide.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Playing around with a graph of the data, as is described in the answer below, on a 14 day moving average the linear best fit curve has an R^2 of ~.93, which isn't awful.  The polynomial with a power of 2 has a best fit R^2 of ~.97, which is pretty decent.  So approximating linear has a marginal drop in accuracy, but not a huge one.  Dropping to just a two power polynomial leaves one with a fairly decent level of accuracy.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - I agree, the *questions* should be the focus. But where do a majority of questions come from whose OP doesn't fully understand the exchange? Perhaps these new users should have a very small barrier to climb in order to post a question at first.

Comment: Assuming exponential growth, every day the number of users multiplies by (3.1m)^(1/2000), about 1.0075. This should match about 23250 new users that day.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I whipped together [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/185609/number-of-created-accounts-per-day) using the Data Explorer which shows you exactly how many users were created on each UTC day. And [even graph the result/growth](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/185609/number-of-created-accounts-per-day#graph)!

[image]

Here's that same graph on a 14 day moving average:

[image]

Then took that information and you can [get an overall average](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/185610/average-user-registrations-per-day). So since Stack Overflow came into existence, the average is 1452 new users per day. That is a little skewed since Stack Overflow started in 2008 with slower growth. [Modifying the query slightly](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/185612), in 2013 was an average of 3138 new users per day, and an average of 3537 users per day in 2014.

Obviously this is probably overkill for what you were looking for. Robert's method is pretty easy to deal with, and uses 100% live data instead of being delayed up to a week.

Comment: Overkill? Never! :) Looks like a good metric to use for this as well.

Comment: It would maybe have been clearer to do an average over each month :-). I _do_ like the fact that it drops of significantly and noticeably around the new year though.

Comment: Your query assumes no users ever got deleted. Or at least only an insignificant number.

Answer (score 8):

[Here's an updated, live query with an adjustable moving average](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/269343/new-accounts-per-day-moving-average?MovingAvg=20#graph):

[image: New User accounts per day]

It looks like the ***rate*** of new account growth has roughly flattened-out since early 2013.

Comment: I wonder why it dips at the New Year timeframe? Christmas? Maybe we are not all geeks after all.

Comment: @nocomprende: *We* are geeks - but we belong to SO already.  Not-yet-geeks tend not to join SO over the holiday.

Comment: @MartinBonner *then* they become geeks, and stay active on the site over major holidays...

Answer (score 6):

If my math is right, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=96&tab=newusers&sort=creationdate), there were approximately 3424 new users who registered on the site since the UTC rollover yesterday.

Comment: Nice, sort by creation data, I did not see that when I was looking for something available in a UI here.