# Brief Educational Quiz before Posting First Questions in Popular Tags

Tags: feature-request

### Withdrawn:

Similar proposal in intent was asked on the old meta (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126945/should-so-have-a-prequalification-process-for-membership-to-weed-out-the-noise/126950#126950), with similar community sentiment.

---

Edit Question Tag Introduction Quiz 
Privilege type: Moderation privilege 
Awarded with Gold Badge on a per tag basis

#### What is a question tag introduction quiz?

When a tag becomes popular, it tends to attract many low quality questions from newer users. A question tag introduction quiz is a short question and answer session designed by respected members of the tag sub-community to:

- Make new users aware of the tag wiki and frequently asked questions.
- Help new users learn how to search for duplicates
- Verify a minimum level of understanding about the subject

#### How does a question tag entry quiz work?

When a user first asks a new question with a tag containing an introduction quiz, that user will be directed to a 5 question quiz specific to that tag. Users scoring less than 4/5 correctly may attempt another quiz with new randomly selected questions from the tag question bank. There is no limit to the number of attempts, however a 2 minute wait period is required between attempts.

New users with low quality questions or questions closed as **duplicates** within the tag will be required to retake the quiz before asking another question.

#### How do I add a new question to the quiz bank?

Access the question bank by clicking the *question tag entry quiz* link in the tag's wiki. New questions are held in a review queue until approved by 3 other gold badge holders within the tag.

#### What makes a good entry quiz question?

Questions should be clearly worded and the answers should be easily found either in the tag's wiki, frequently asked questions, or from general *minimal* working knowledge about the subject. The quiz is intended to *educate* newcomers, not prevent them.

#### When does the question tag introduction quiz become activated?

In order to activate the question tag introduction quiz, there must be a quorum of 7 gold badge holders for the tag and a bank of at least 20 questions and answers. At least 5 gold badge holders must vote to active the quiz.

Comment: This seems just as likely to annoy/drive away expert users as it would people looking to have their homework done for them.

Comment: @Servy This is _ask_ for the _first_ time in a tag. The quiz questions would be of the level to be answerable by an expert in ~30 seconds. Less annoying than a captcha in my opinion. A novice would have to spend a few minutes ~5 looking at the wiki. If they are too impatient for that, well...

Comment: There are *lots* of subject experts that don't have accounts on SO and need to create an account to ask a question.  Not all subject experts already have SO accounts.  Asking one of those people to spend several minutes going through super introductory questions *is* likely to be annoying, and may well be enough for them to just give up and try another site.  Combine that with low quality, unclear, or just straight up wrong questions that could easily pass through a review system like that, and I could *absolutely* see them driven away.

Comment: Withdrawing this proposal as essentially already made in intent (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126945/should-so-have-a-prequalification-process-for-membership-to-weed-out-the-noise/126950#126950), thanks @gitsitgo, with similar community sentiment. I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: I can see the practical problems, but I do wish we could ask first-timers for [double] and [floating-point] whether they know what is meant by "floating point rounding error" and show them the [floating-point] Wiki if they answer "no".

Comment: This reeks of elitism and will surely dissuade plenty of potentially good contributors from bothering with this site ever again after their first question/tag attempt.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I also don't see how this will solve the problem. Let's say the quiz is implemented, it will probably serve its purpose for certain portion of new users.

But consider this, some of those new users will just end up tagging their questions other tags (possibly wrong ones too). Then along comes a regular SO member doing his/her job, and they re-tag the question without realizing that the new user bypassed the quiz. Just like this, the quizzing system is easily defeated.

And then you'd have to maintain new quiz questions in a question bank, with a quiz question review queue too? You have to realize, this is **a lot** of work for a mechanism that can be easily bypassed. This is what I believe Makoto means when he says your idea is counterproductive.

Furthermore, this is the reason why we have the first post review queue, which at least covers *all* questions of any tags. So if low quality questions are appearing, I would think we need to tackle problems in existing mechanisms first, such as robo-reviewers.

Comment: So, you disagree because you find it easily defeatable (excellent point, but I think those would be in the minority and regular SO users would be savvy to it pretty quickly), or also because you think it is a bad idea in general. I think Makoto is saying this idea is counterproductive because he feels it would alienate newer users, which was not my intent.

Comment: @A.Webb Yes, easily defeatable and also because there is a mechanism in place already to stem the tide of low quality first posts (first post review queue). Your idea would most likely diminish a good bunch of low quality posts from happening, but at the cost of a lot of effort. It's not a bad idea per se, but it's an idea with holes in it.

Answer (score 8):

No.   ***Hell*** no.

I don't see any reason to add such a feature to the site.  I don't even see what it could possibly *gain* us.

The argument is that one is trying to prevent low quality questions from seeping into popular tags.  Well, supposing that this approach were to work, the less popular tags would still have low quality questions in there as well.

The way I view this:  You're placing another barrier to participation within the community.  That's counter-productive, and would result in a significant decrease in newer people participating.

Perhaps question and answer quality is a lot lower nowadays than it was before.  Perhaps.  But I don't see this as any sort of solution to that problem.

Comment: Less popular tags handle the few low quality questions they get just fine already. The problem is scale. This is intended as an absolutely _minimal_ demonstration of interest, not an elitist barrier to entry. Right now it is quicker to ask a duplicate question than to search for an existing answer, and that is precisely what new users do en masse on popular tags.

Comment: But it's **yet another barrier** to participation.  If it's an issue of duplicate questions, then the notification on when someone posts a dupe should be stronger (or there should be more incentive to find one).  I just don't feel like this is going to help anything at all; it may even put up barriers for the truly new, but inquisitive.

Comment: I don't follow your reasoning. You say a barrier is counterproductive, but the only explanation you give is that it will decrease the number of new people participating. _That is the point._ In what way do you feel that this barrier would keep out the good users or fail to stop the bad ones?

Comment: Another barrier? What are the existing barriers? Established users getting mad and downvoting/closing? This _brief_ educational process would help reduce that.

Comment: I suppose I'm a bit tired of seeing all of the questions like this that seem to paint new users with the same brush.  I feel like it would stymie newer discussions, even from those "good" users - because we've introduced another hurdle for them to get over.  The whole idea was that anyone could ask a question - they didn't even need an account to do it with.  Why are we trying to have a double-edged sword here; welcome newbies with open arms, but shun them from asking a question?

Comment: @A.Webb:  There's a lot of mental inertia one has to overcome to get their question reopened after it's been closed and (likely) downvoted into oblivion.  While I don't disagree with that process necessarily, adding more on top of that doesn't seem like it'd help the situation any.  We could run the risk of filtering out the experts-in-training with this approach, too.

Comment: @Makoto I am trying to _prevent_ new users from experiencing closed questions / being downvoted by _educating_ them. I am proposing about 5 minutes of investment for a new user to ask their _first_ question. Is that _really_ to much to expect to join the community? If they already have _minimal_ knowledge about the subject, the questions are intended to be immediately answerable. Otherwise, they learn how to look at the wiki and the FAQs. Not a big deal!

Comment: @A.Webb you might be interested in the first part of this [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126950) which is slightly related to your feature req.

Comment: @gitsitgo Yes, thank you. It is the same intent with the same community sentiment judging by the votes. I withdrawal this proposal.