# Programming Quiz to be able to ask questions

Tags: feature-request, question-quality

It seems like almost every question I review is people asking to do their work for them or questions already answered on stack.

To weed out some of these poor questions perhaps we should Implement a Programming Quiz, or Captcha in order to be able to ask questions. This could be applied only for new user's or people who have a reputation of asking bad questions.

Now, you might say that what would stop people from just looking up the answers online?  That would be a valid point, but by people having to look up the answers to these questions online, they might just re-think asking their question or at least attempting to research their question first instead of having to research these quiz questions instead.  Also, it would help people get into the flow of R & D, it seems like more and more people are trying to develop without doing the proper research.

Comment: Are you proposing this happen for every question, or just before asking their first?  If the former, it might help, as it being more work to ask a question would increase the likelihood that the user just googling their own question would be easier than asking SO users to google their question for them.  If the latter, then it would only be relevant for their first question, and thereafter, there's no longer an incentive to not ask trivially googleable questions on SO.

Comment: A quiz should happen when you sign up in order to ask questions, and a captcha should occur if you consistently ask bad questions, until you can ask a valid question

Comment: Sounds a lot like [Brief Educational Quiz before Posting First Questions in Popular Tags](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252829/215552)...

Comment: How are you proposing to write a programming quiz that everyone can do, given there's such a huge range of tags. If I only know C and only want to ask a question about that would I need to tell you something about object orientation. If I know C++ would you demand that I did know about object orientation.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254448/should-so-have-a-prequalification-process-for-membership-to-weed-out-the-noise . The linked question is about adding additional requirements for *site membership*, which might consist of a quiz or some other (non-quiz) requirement. This question is about requiring passing a quiz in order to *post a question*. That is certainly related and based on the same general idea (increase site quality), but marking them as duplicate is like saying we should throw away our ovens because we have microwaves.

Comment: @RobertColumbia See the OP's first comment; he's really looking for it to happen when they ask their first question, which I don't see as meaningfully different from doing so on registration.

Answer (score 8):

When these kind of questions are downvoted often enough, the result is that these kind of users will be banned from asking questions altogether. In some sense, Stack Overflow *is* already a Programming Quiz and we, the Community, are the quiz-masters.

Feature requests to make asking a question a privilege (at, say, 10 reputation) have been proposed [before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254194/a-tiny-barrier-to-entry), but were rejected.

Comment: Well, at least until they create a new account to ask questions with.

Comment: Isn't that detected as well (unless they clear their browser cache and use a different IP address)?

Comment: A mod is likely to catch them and merge the accounts.  That doesn't stop them from asking the first question though.  They just need to create a new account for each question.