# Make (some of the) help pages as questions / answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request, help-center

#### TL;DR: what about going, for help pages, from:

[image]

#### to:

[image]

#### ?

---

The content of this [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (for example) is very useful for Stack Overflow users. But as I'm used to the traditional Q&A layout on Stack Overflow (that makes the reading very "dynamic" and appealing), I find the layout of [these help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) a bit boring in its somewhat-old-documentation-style... Am I the only one?

Isn't there a way to make most help pages more "fresh" and more attractive ... **by using the usual Q&A design that made the success of Stack Overflow**? (in the same way the voting process also cleverly reused the standard Q&A style)

Example:

> Question:
>
> How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example? Why is it useful when posting a question on Stack Overflow?

and

> Answer (community wiki):
>
> When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. That code ...

Comment: @Clay07g Yes... I added example screenshots in the top of question to show more the idea.

Comment: But the rules in the help center are decided by the company, right? The [faq](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faq) pages are presented Q&A style with community wiki answers because those are decided by the community. (Or are the community's consensus on how to interpret/enforce the existing rules)

Comment: @BSMP Yes, but then it's possible to have only one answer by "StackOverflowCompany" (instead of "Community wiki") on those help pages. I'm mostly speaking about layout to make them more appealing.

Comment: I can't see how this will help - It might even make it more confusing. The format of Q&A implies that the content is dynamic while the content of the help center pages is actually static

Comment: I definitely like the idea of making this information more discoverable for new users, but I fear that this might lead users to ask questions about Stack Overflow on Stack Overflow instead of here on Meta. (Come to think of it, all of that information is probably already here in some form, but it can still be hard to find.)

Comment: The [tour] is fancy, lightweighted on text, goes to the core of what the site's about, and folks **don't** read it :(

Comment: @brasofilo Because what new visitors expect on SO is the usual Q&A layout. Everything else seems disturbing or noisy or unimportant-documentation. This.

Answer (score 4):

The Q&A format is not a panacea, some magical salve you can spread over any problem to make it better. It exists to serve a purpose: cataloging solutions (answers) based on the problems (questions).

That doesn't really help here. The problem is not how the information is catalogued; it's how often it's read and followed. Too many users don't *care* about making an MCVE even if they know what it is.

Also, your example is two entirely separate questions. How to write an MCVE is a separate question from why it's important to have one. So your question should be "closed" for being too broad ;)

Comment: Where did I really say, in the naive way you're referring to, that Q&A is a solution to *any* problem?

Comment: `to serve a purpose: cataloging solutions (answers) based on the problems (questions).` It's the case for most help topics. Question: *How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example?* Answer: ...

Comment: @Basj: I fail to see how restating the same thing as the docs improves things. This is the sort of thinking that led to Docs.SO.

Comment: @NicolasBolas  I didn't speak about *restating* (and finally having two documents: Q&A + help page), but *replacing* the original content by a Q&A layout. And yes, changing the *design/layout/form* even without modifying *the content* can sometimes improve things.

Comment: But FAQs do have this Q&A form.

Answer (score 2):

The help center is currently a condensed version of the outlook from Stack Overflow as a company. Most of it was written by Community Management, and some of it dates back to Jeff and Joel.

However, *almost all of it* has been discussed on meta already, so basically any nuance that someone would be curious enough to search for already exists.

Given that, I don't see the benefit in converting entire help pages into Q&A format because most of them already have several if not dozens of associated meta discussion.

Moreover, there is also the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) which has semi official help center associated Q&A's there right now.

On top of all of this, if there is something in the help center which needs to be edited, just open a feature request and ask for it to be changed. Where warranted, it will be generally be made if it is narrow. The same goes for proposing [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) posts.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't imply "help topics as Q&A" should be converted to discussions in metaSO (then, yes, it would be hard to search in it among hundreds of posts). It could just help to have a less boring layout than documentation-that-noone-reads-just-by-looking-at-the-layout.

Comment: @Basj - Perhaps you could come up with something that fits a little better in place on the page to what you are envisioning? The Q&A format doesn't particularly fit with a help center page, if that is what you were getting at, in my opinion. That said, I don't think having a date posted, number of views, and perhaps a place to vote would necessarily be bad ideas for help pages. Perhaps votes and views could factor into their weight for how visible they are.