#      ?

Tags: discussion, title

I came across a question where the user formatted the title with text in bold and italics. I thought that question titles were stripped of all formatting and was surprised to see this. I'm assuming that this is just a Unicode trick, but should it be allowed? It seems like something that has the potential for abuse.

For those that don't see the fully formatted title, here's an image of this question's title:

[image: "should formatting in titles be permitted?" written in various non-ascii unicode characters]
<sub>*Note that different browsers on different devices and operating systems may yield different results.*</sub>

Comment: Interestingly, it does not break [search](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%22Should+formatting%22)

Comment: This is not formatting. These are non-ASCII Unicode characters. Are you asking if titles should be restricted to some particular set of characters?

Comment: @zaq yes, however it *appears* to the average user as if the title text has been formatted.

Comment: [Not *all* formatting is allowed](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Ccy_UkaUEAMs4nF.jpg)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker no one said all formatting is allowed

Comment: ˙ʇɔnpoɹd ɹo ʇuǝʌǝ sıɥʇ ǝsɹopuǝ ʎʃıʇɹɐǝɥ I

Comment: Interesting, the space between d and F appears to be a square... is OP using some shady character... I'm afraid to ask.

Comment: But seriously now. I can read most of it, but not the last word. Can anybody recommend a font to download? So a font that would contain the "Enclosed Alphanumeric Supplement" block, right?

Comment: Interestingly, Firefox cuts off this title way too early in the tab bar.

Comment: Not only does Firefox cut it off early, it cuts it off in the middle of a surrogate pair. I get "Shou[D835]..." in my tab bar.

Comment: Safari and Chrome on OS X gets this 100% right everywhere on the page and in the UI. An excellent testament to superior Unicode support on that platform.

Comment: @CodyGray, Chromium on Linux gets it 100% right too, including in the window title.

Comment: Earlier, I only saw the "Permitted?" part on my iPad. *Quelle surprise*, on my desktop I see "Should Formatting in Titles be P?". So it takes some mental assembling to get what it is supposed to say.

Comment: Perhaps someone on a system that displays the title in its full glory can add a screenshot so we can see what we are missing out on.

Comment: You really aren't [missing very much](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3G03a.png), @martin.

Comment: @CodyGray - Thanks. The ipad only shows the "Permitted" part - with the P rendered in blue and the rest black!

Comment: It's bwutiful I want!

Comment: If you can't see the entire title, download a font that supports almost all unicode characters, like Google's [Noto font](https://www.google.com/get/noto/) or any of the [other fonts](http://unicode.org/resources/fonts.html) recommended by the Unicode Consortium

Comment: @CodyGray Has nothing to do with the platform: http://www2.pic-upload.de/img/32537433/Formatting.png Firefox on Windows 10, Chrome works as well. More likely related to the setup of the system.

Comment: Your "P" is a different color, @lwchris. You should have a doctor look at that.

Comment: Smilies works also in comments 

Comment: @CodyGray Parking emoji, see http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f17f/index.htm Not that I'd ever need it. Although... https://twitter.com/LyricWikiChris/status/612389124218208257

Comment: @CodyGray you have to [thank hichrist123 for it...](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=4970813#4970813) [It was absolutely terribad some years ago.](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3354982#3354982)

Comment: How does search still works ? If "" != "S" just like "Ä" != "A" or "ß" != "B"

Comment: [This question provides interesting results in the tab <title> bar](https://i.gyazo.com/e8eef4b5dcc477333c8fcbc5cd2e1d3d.png)

Comment: [Coincidentally, this works pretty well for our D&D group chat](http://i.imgur.com/SSYMzNu.png)

Comment: @BenVoigt, it does break search, the permitted part isn't searchable

Comment: Absolutely not!

Comment: My attention surely was caught up by this title.

Comment: [Reporting in from Firefox on Linux with a broken title](http://i.imgur.com/wcm5M2f.png). I'd say avoid this unless your question directly relates to issues with these kinds of characters.

Comment: I don't know if we should allow this.  Next in Unicode: CSS and SVG support

Comment: My only regret is that I didn't think of that trick myself.

Comment: Š̻̰̜̥͇̼̦́̌̂̎͋̓ũ̺̲͓͔͍̯̃̋̈̃̇̓̿̕͝r̶̭̹̘͕̣̀̉̇͗̅̀è̵̤̖̗̮̱͙̼̤̰̟͂̌̎̓̒,̰̝͉̮͙̩̘͎͕̇̏̏̌͊̚ w̵̧̘̣̼͙̬̔́̏̅͊̂ḫ̡̫̘̯̙͚̑̅́́̏̒̋͘͡y̫̠͔̯̮͔̭͉̭̓̐̏̂̀̈́͑̅̚ͅ n̶̖̩͕̳̟̗̄͆̎̾̀̐̒̈́̀ő̴̧̱͕̫̥̥͉͔̰̯̃̏̿̾̅͠t̴̡̛̛̫̲̮̰̦̱̋̒͑͋̉͊̽͒͟?͙̥͕͖̟͔͊̈́͒͂͐͊̑̃͘͝

Comment: Where do I click YES or NO?

Comment: I can see everything except the word "Permitted". Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: It should be noted that these unicode characters do not render on all OS's. Works fine on my mac in chrome but just boxes on my iPhone

Comment: [Fun](http://m.imgur.com/w12d6zc).

Comment: I wonder how this question got so many upvotes :/

Comment: It has potential for use and abuse. Because I don't generally see titles like this, I think it's something that's best moderated on a case-by-case basis. @CodyGray Chrome 55 renders all the text on Windows 10. I do think that SO would benefit from a user option to automagically convert unicode characters to something their inferior ASCII fonts/browsers can display.

Comment: If this question has established one thing then it's that using these characters in the title certainly works in getting people's attention!

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: ... and lots of upvotes .... Perhaps we are, kind of, you know, sending the wrong signal here?

Comment: @CodyGray Windows 10 with Chrome gets this also 100% right.

Comment: teach me, master @lxer

Comment: Hah! Thanks @clearlight, I always find stuff for others but never for myself...

Comment: Couldn't resist "fixing" the title a little, to make it clearer for users that can't see the characters.

Comment: @Cerbrus Apparently you couldn't resist ;) Thanks, but I prefer it the way it was

Comment: Yea, couldn't resist "fixing" the title a little, to make it clearer for users that can't see the characters. @j08691: The current title is invisible to some users, which makes the question unclear at first sight. The short description I added immediately makes it obvious what the issue is, especially if you can't see the title. I'd really recommend adding it back.

Comment: @Cerbrus That's part of the issue (problem?) actually. I also just updated the question with an image.

Comment: @j08691: My point is that the issue isn't clear on meta's front page, if you don't see the title. You just see a question mark. (At least that's not in unicode). Imo, _"Apparently there's an issue with unicode in titles"_ is better than _"Eh, that question looks broken"_, on the front page.

Comment: Unicode is insane.  Do you want stackoverflow to be MORE insane?  Stick to standard letters in titles please.  Search features will be damaged when people use non searchable Unicode in titles.

Comment: Never saw any misuse of this type.

Comment: Doesn't work on the page in Firefox 45, Mac OS X Snow Leopard, but its ok in the titlebar for some reason...

Comment: @devRicher Looks like the OS trying to display a character not supported/invalid byte sequence in the title.

Comment: @astonearachnid It is only possible in ubuntu.

Comment: People might want to format to get more attention to their question. If it works, everyone will want to start formatting. If everyone started formatting, Stack OverFlow would be a mess!

Comment: @AnnZen If somebody did that, we'd undo it, and if they insisted on doing it, we'd warn and, if they *still* persisted, we'd then suspend them. It's a non-issue, no different than people who type their question titles entirely in uppercase. This has never been a problem in the history of the site.

Comment: @meagar I just noticed something... This question's title is formatted! (just kidding) Anyway, the reason I read this question is not because I searched it, it's the formatting that caught my eye!

Answer (score 468):

What if I have the question:

> Why does my program stop working if I use characters such as ""?

Disallowing this sort of stuff would also disallow legitimate uses. The legitimate uses may be rare ([though they do exist](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43618487/660921)), but so are the *illegitimate* uses. I've never seen it once in 4+ years of Stack Overflow.

It's fixed quickly enough with an edit in the rare occasion that it occurs.

Comment: And if a specific user persists in using such titles, feel free to flag for mod attention and we'll have a word.

Comment: I assume one wouldn't disallow all letter-likes in titles, but a rule like "at least 50% ASCII (except on ja.so, ru.so and math.se)" should work just fine.

Comment: -1 It's enough to use the name or class of the character, like "asterisk", and also improves the searchability of the question.

Comment: You could (and probably should) be using ``U+1d4e2`` (codepoint), ``Mathematical Bold Script Capital S`` (name of the character) or "Mathematical alphanumeric symbols" (name of the unicode block) instead of ````. That improves searchability (especially the last two options) of the question a lot.

Comment: Using the name of the character is great, so long as we can all agree on what it's called. What do you call `#`? Number sign? Hash sign? Pound sign? Octothorpe (and any of its many spelling variations)? `Mathematical Bold Script Capital S` would make for an awfully long title. But all of these comments really miss the point, and that is that [blacklists suck](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107989/why-cant-we-use-the-word-problem-in-titles).

Comment: @Cody Gray: Clearly, it's called a "hashtag", since that's what everybody insists on calling it these days!

Comment: @JonasWielicki: Nothing against giving the name, but why "instead of"? What's wrong with "Program stops working when given mathematical alphanumeric symbols such as ''"?

Comment: @CodyGray Whatever name you choose it is infinitely more searchable than the symbol, which is too short for search engines to allow as a keyword. As for the "S", disallowing the symbol would make the questioner run tests to determine if the question pertains to unicode text, only to unicode text that is bolded, etc. This makes the question more accurate and useful to others.

Comment: @Spaghetti You assume that people asking questions about this sort of stuff know about such things. It's likely that they don't – that's why they're asking a question!

Comment: @Carpetsmoker That they don't know what is unicode? I think it's reasonable to assume that people can tell the difference between ASCII and non-ASCII, given they code and write their question in ASCII. "Why does my program crash on non-ASCII characters?" is better than "Why [...] on 'S'?" simply because it's more searchable and broad enough to be useful to other people.

Comment: @Spaghetti I don't disagree there are better titles than what I put in the question; that's why you can edit it! However, it's also not a *wholly unreasonable title* for a user to use, and I think that disallowing it would do more harm than good.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker well I'm unconvinced, because you didn't make the case for what the harm is in banning unicode; what are the legitimate uses that outweigh the disadavantages I mentioned in my previous comments?

Comment: @ruakh Point taken.

Comment: 1990: "128 characters aren't enough. We need more"
2016: "There are so many Unicode characters it's difficult to identify those that can be used inappropriately"

Comment: *“given they code and write their question in ASCII”* – I neither write code nor questions/answers in ASCII.

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41879957/stanford-corenlp-and-emoji

Answer (score 133):

Is this actually a widespread problem? Seems like nobody's actually abusing it, and any isolated case can be handled with a warning and/or suspension.

Considering that legitimate titles would likely be blocked by any naive approach and beyond that we'd be in a "tweak this block so it doesn't prevent this legit issue but also block other malicious approaches" hell... and given that this is merely annoying to the eye and fixable with a quick edit... I'm inclined to advocate against any preemptive fixes.

Comment: So "should it be allowed", yes (as in "not explicitly hardcoded to be *not* allowed") but *also* "please edit it out when seen"?

Comment: It’s not merely annoying. It prevents display of the title for those whose font does not support whole Unicode.

Comment: @Palec That's only a problem for illegitimate uses. If there is a legitimate reason to use such a character, your inability to view it is *your* problem.

Comment: Or problem of the asker who drives me away from answering, @chepner.

Comment: Still, my first comment related to the “given that this is merely annoying to the eye and fixable with a quick edit” part, @chepner. This clearly talks about illegitimate uses, which are supposedly easy to fix by editing.

Comment: Wait for the first dancing hamster emoji title

Comment: Waiting for the first honest user to use the "happy poop" emoji...

Comment: @Palec Fix your god-damned broken system then. *Everybody* system can be relied on to have one, it's just a lot of *software* that's broken (and, fun fact, illegal in China because of it).

Comment: I do see _one_ person abusing it.

Answer (score 75):

I don't know why this needs reiterating in 2017, although looking around me at various goings on lately you're surely not alone in falling foul of it. But, to be clear then:

#### Use your common sense.

Is the formatting semantically important? Is the author asking a question about a Unicode character?

- Then it's fine.

Is the title all rendered in Unicode trickery for the sake of drawing attention and being obnoxious?

- Edit it out.

The logical consequence is also that there can be no automated system to "filter out" such happenings, not that those systems ever work terribly well anyway.

I don't see why any discussion is required beyond that. It's the same logic we apply to the post itself.

Comment: *"I don't know why this needs reiterating in 2017, although looking around me at various goings on lately you're surely not alone in falling foul of it."* An alternative conclusion would be that common sense is not all that common. But I couldn't agree more with the spirit of this answer. We don't need a "rule" for every little thing.

Comment: What about a couple of words in UNICODE italics to add emphasis or clarification to a dependent clause, but not ostentatious?

Comment: @clearlight: No.

Answer (score 42):

Put it this way: you'd probably frown on any of the following:

*** Should formatting in titles be permitted? ***

or

Should-formatting-in-titles-be-permitted?

<sup>[(I actually caught someone posting a question with a title that's literally the URL slug of an unrelated forum thread, dashes and all, just the other day)](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41735472/1)</sup>

or

-=[ Should formatting in titles be permitted? ]=-

or

ShOuLd FoRmAtTiNg In TiTlEs Be PeRmItTeD?

or

5|-|0|_|1|) |=0|2|\/|477i|\|9 i|\| 7i7135 |33 |>3|2|\/|i773|)?

The 1337 example is especially similar to yours: like it, it makes use of characters that *clearly* mean something other than, well, parts of letterforms, for something that's not their intended meaning or purpose. Anyone who can read 1337 will understand the 1337 example, and there are 1337 translation sites out there that will translate it for you (I wrote it entirely by hand, though), but to everyone else this title might as well be complete gibberish.

The fact that *not everyone can even see the characters in your example* alone should be enough of a case against such titles.

Comment: d00d! |_| |` 4 1337 h4x0r!!11!one

Comment: Oh, TiTlEs are certainly permitted.

Comment: I never realized I could read 1337 text. Now I wish I didn't. It looked so eerie before, now it's just snowflakes trying to be more unique... ;)

Comment: As an aside, that l33tsp34k version could be a decent password, if anyone could remember it.  Not necessarily _good_, but at least long and complex enough to deter casual crackers, and with a built-in hint.

Comment: *“I wrote it entirely by hand, though”* – You really wanted to point that out, huh? :P

Comment: @JustinTime An interesting strategy, but not a very good one, given that it's relatively easy to create a dictionary attack that also swaps characters with their 1337 alternatives. LastPass + randomly-generated, per-site passwords is a much more secure (and more convenient) solution.

Comment: @NathanArthur True.  Just pointing out that it's enough to stop casual cracking, usually, and relatively simple to remember.  If someone wanted to make a good password by hand, I would recommend a multi-word password that employs a mix of misspellings, l33t, and "l33t-lite", such as turning [`correcthorsebatterystaple`](https://xkcd.com/936/) into `kH0Rr3k+|-|oR$|=|34tTerRyztAp1e`; still not as secure as a generated password, but [a decent tester](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/209/zxcvbn/test/index.html) says the latter is significantly better than the former.

Answer (score 20):

I believe the answer should be "**NO**, this should not be allowed." Reasons why are covered by other answers, but the big one is there are a number of situations where the titles just won't display correctly at all, even for people who would otherwise understand them.

**BUT**

Then you get to the question of enforcement. I don't think it's a good idea to change anything at all in the code-base towards enforcing it. Rather, I'd like to see this formally listed as one of the question guidelines, and then leave it up to the community to enforce via edits and flags, as already happens.

Listing it as a rule might help ward off additional abuse, but mostly the idea is to encourage users that this is an okay reason to edit or flag, and to give moderators something to point at if the need arises.

Effectively, this should work much like the duplicates and other filters. While duplicates are technically forbidden, occasionally a duplicate question comes up that still manages to find an audience, words things in a creative new way that helps pull in Google traffic towards the issue, or sometimes just misses close votes... and that the filter is imperfect in this way is a feature, not a bug. The same thing can work here, has already worked here.

Answer (score 13):

I may be mistaken, but I believe that Unicode does have a way to transform such "formatted" characters back into their original, unformatted forms. If that is the case, we need not discard all of Unicode just to prevent people from doing this. We merely need to employ that mechanism to get rid of certain unpleasant codepoints.

Maybe if more than half of your title contains "formatted" codepoints that map to regular characters, we can prevent them from posting.

Edit: Below is a screenshot of what this posts title looks like in its current form, ala unformatted:
[image: Unformatted Unicode Displaying in a Browser Tab]

Comment: Yeah that's called normalization. À to A and é to e and so on. I don't really see a reason to use characters with accents on the English Stack Overflow, as English hardly, if ever, uses accented characters. But for Portuguese and so on...

Comment: @CodeCaster Unicode normalisation *never* strips accents (or other combining sequences), but will replace font variants with their equivalent, plain forms (such as in the title of this question).

Comment: @CodeCaster no, that's not what normalization is. The normalized form of À is À (or À), and the normalized form of  is . Downconverting to ASCII (or something like) is a different task that the Unicode data doesn't *really* provide for, although there are tools to be had (like Text::Unidecode).

Comment: I mean NFKD, normalization through decomposition, which you can then strip the combining characters from. Again, might be useful for English where you generally only use A-Z in titles (in the letters class at least), but not for other cases.

Comment: @CodeCaster unless you are Tom Christiansen, you are in lot of trouble.

Comment: @CodeCaster generally, yes - but as we are programmers, it's not uncommon to encounter charset-spesific problems that can have pretty much any character

Comment: actually it is called accentfolding. If you google it you can see it is not a simple task

Comment: Instead of normalizing, it would be more useful to simply show the XML encoding of the character (e.g. &#233;) above a certain value (to exclude accents from the same treatment... You still have the source character value but you cannot use it for formatting.

Comment: @CodeCaster: unless you have trouble implementing the `<non-English author>` algorithm…

Comment: @CodeCaster most of the characters you would want to clean up don't decompose.

Comment: @Braiam He’s in a lot of trouble.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Talk about [déjà vu](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/d%C3%A9j%C3%A0_vu#Noun) - [à la](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A0_la#Preposition) memory - [vis-à-vis](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vis-%C3%A0-vis#Adverb) to remember something. Or perhaps it is time for a [coup d'état](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/coup_d%27%C3%A9tat#Noun)?

Comment: @Peter yeah, forget everything I said in this comment thread three and a half years ago.

Answer (score 2):

Weighing both positives and negatives I would probably say no. The number of questions asked by new members is exponentially more than old members and if formatting is allowed then people wont just use it for the context presented by op.

n number of questions will float around with formatting just to beautify stuff(from their perspective) or just to make it look different - well that is human nature, cannot ignore it.

And it is not that critical a point, you can simply use words to represent that symbol and then you can explain it properly in main text.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very relevant question to meta, so kudos to you.

I agree that unicode characters have potential for use and abuse, however I have yet to see titles formatted this way, and I'm inclined to think the abuse is minimal. As such, I think this is best moderated on a case-by-case basis. It should be frowned upon due to the implicit expectation that users have a fully-compliant Unicode browser and font.

However it can also serve a constructive purpose in that it can be used to provide emphasis or explanation that ASCII cannot. The most immediate examples are questions about programs crashing while parsing certain unicode byte sequences. I've encountered a few such programs and it is helpful to be able to distribute the sequence for testing purposes as part of a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example.

---

To elaborate on my stance, I'm definitely not against the use of unicode in titles for subtle formatting and emphasis. But because it limits the ability of some users on older platforms to examine the question quickly, it may be a prudent idea to include a user account setting to *automatically convert unicode into ASCII*, where converted text is given some form of formatting to differentiate it from ordinary text. Perhaps emboldening it and wrapping it in // may help. Users with older browsers who enabled the feature would see your title as **/Should Formatting in Titles Be Permitted/**, for example. EDIT: My mobile phone actually only displays "[boxes] Permitted", so a setting like this may have a much wider benefit than I initially thought.

Though it's inevitable that an implementation will still occasionally garble the text, even a small degree of support will greatly improve the experience on SO for those unfortunate users who can't view some portions of unicode.

A simpler option is to detect the use of unicode on a page and produce a banner that politely suggests a browser and font (one for each major OS) that are known to play nicely, if the viewer happens to be seeing boxes or question marks everywhere. Along the lines of *"We've noticed this question contains Unicode characters. If you are having trouble viewing them, these configurations seem to work well: ..."*

Comment: OK‚ if by ”detect the use of unicode on a page” you mean ”detect the use of lesser-used characters”. Otherwise‚ everything is Unicode and everybody would always get the banner…

Comment: Good point. I wasn't sure how difficult it would be to define which characters are less used, though a good start is any utf8 beyond the first 7 bits. Handling and displaying unicode is a responsibility of the browser, so I don't think an elaborate solution is necessary. Just enough to point a user in the right direction of they have trouble.

Answer (score 1):

There *is* **one** thing that needs to be blocked: any character with a General Category of `Cc` (Other, control), `Cf` (Other, format), `Cs` (Other, surrogate), or `Co` (Other, private-use), and the 66 characters that are permanently in `Cn` (Other, not assigned, specifically the noncharacters).

Everything else should be permitted, including characters that might move out of `Cn` in future versions (that is, Other, not assigned, reserved).

While there are a *few* characters from `Cf` that might be whitelisted, but that would be done on a case-by-case basis, as much of `Cf` is outright dangerous.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: much better, thanks. As for this answer: yes, these codes may (could?) be used for malicious intent. However, the question is about abuse to *draw attention*.

Comment: Could you elaborate why these characters would be dangerous in the context of a question title?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker because they make programs do weird things - and they *remain* in effect for following text. Some in the browser, some when copy-pasted out. RTL marks in particular are nasty.

Comment: @o11c Yeah, ⅃ΤЯ is pretty unfriendly, ¡ʇɐɥʇ uɐɥʇ sƃuᴉɥʇ əsɹoʍ ʍouʞ I ʇnq

Answer (score -8):

Formatting is for one purpose: highlight some text and/or make it overall more readable. It should not be overused - no matter where: in comments, or in answers or questions, or even in titles. If it's allowed, there should be a way for moderators or privileged users to remove that formatting. There should be a button called `edit title`, available to users with certain reputation. This also would be useful for removing any swear words or other otherwise nonallowed text. If formatting's not misused or overused, it should remain - it does the same thing in titles that it does in comments, questions and answers.

---

**EDIT 1** There already is a mechanism for editing titles, so let's just edit overformatted titles it when we can.

Comment: We can already edit the title when we open up the edit screen on any question. Try pressing edit on a question on Stack Overflow (Not meta since you don't have the rep yet) and you'll see that the title is there ready to be edited.

Answer (score -11):

I think that there should be a rule that indicates when we can use this kind of formatting and when it's not permitted to use it. As was stated earlier, there are some people who have problems with formatting and need to make their questions more understandable, so totally banning it wouldn't do much.

Comment: The fact that the title field is a simple single-line text field that only accepts plain text should be enough of an indication that only plain text titles are acceptable.

Comment: You *say* that, but what about the people who try and post their entire code in a comment, @boltclock?

Comment: I don't follow, @Cody. Code dump comments are subject to flagging and deletion all the same.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Oh, the fact that the comment field is multiline despite line breaks being ignored in comments? Yeah, you got me there.

Comment: No, I really meant that it should be completely obvious that multi-line code blocks don't belong in comments, yet they get posted there all the time. Of course, they are subject to flagging and deletion. So would be questions with these types of titles. @boltclock

Comment: @CodyGray: That's where "should be" comes in ;) It's clear to us sensible folk, and we can clean up after the rest of them

Comment: The problem with some of these policies is that many people who haven't been part of the meta discussion don't anticipate them or have the distilled rationale. Seems like the system, upon detecting UNICODE might pop-up a warning about proper/improper use before letting someone submit a question with a UNICODE title if there is really a strict policy about it, in order to give people fair notice. A lot of people here  act like "Because I said so!" and "ignorance of the law is no excuse", but fair warning is only fair otherwise it's just authoritarian and punitive like a speed trap or worse.

Comment: Some people are of the temperament that before you can use the site you have to RTFM, all of it, everywhere, but the reality is people don't necessarily all have the time or inclination to get into every nook and cranny of how Stack Overflow works, and it takes time, even if one is open to learning, and people need to know the priority stuff, and things slip through the cracks. For serious rules like this it seems like the warnings should be more prominent.

Comment: It is NOT obvious that *any* use of formatting, even let's say a single italicized word, would be heavily frowned on by the authorities here.

Answer (score -13):

Coming to Stack Overflow only about a year ago, new both to non GUI, OSX Terminal, and Stack Exchange(SE) generally, I offer the following thoughts.

I suggest that formatted titles should be a permission granted in the form of a new permission after reaching a certain reputation point level, and possibly a badge.

For a completely new user to SE, there is a novelty in learning how to use formatting in ones answers to questions. Also one is still acquiring an appreciation of the underlying order and flow that has been so carefully crafted in SE.

At this stage it would be very tempting to play with formatting in a posted question, not appreciating the context, common practice, and standards.

While such practice is currently rare, I suggest that is in part because, viewing questions formatting is absent, one assumes it is not done or possible.  However if some newer users begin to use it, and other newer users see it used, that 'rarity' may change. Or it may not. I speculate.

If new users are tempted to play with formatting in questions eg make a question all bold to attract attention, this could lead to more experienced users increased overheads in time to respond to inappropriate use of formatting.

If formatting in questions is allowed after say 200 reputation points, and with possibly a badge, not only has the experience curve of 'typical practice' been acquired by the SE participant, and the initial novelty of SE posting worn off, but the badge can reference the need to only use formatting when required as necessary to present a special character or similar to make the question clear to its purpose, as opposed to just making bold to try and get more attention.

I think this would be a good 'balance' of considerations.

In this way, more experienced users over say 200 reputation points can edit a question to add an appropriate format if such is called for, for clarity.

The 200 reputation may not be the correct experience level, but used as an example.

I lack the experience to have the nuance to see how to implement in the reputation and badge system, but I think the suggestion as a possible contributing thought to a solution is made clear.

Comment: Wow, a genuine view, a genuine contribution, and so many negative votes with no comment as to why? I thought stack exchange meta was to air ideas.  I suspect, given lack of any comments as to why that this is simply idea stacking, like branch stacking.  Ouch. I can not afford the consequence of down votes, so I am going to delete this contribution shortly.

Comment: The problem with making title formatting a privilege is that it would only make sense if title formatting was useful, and by and large it isn't. Question body formatting, on the other hand, is extremely useful, and should be available to everyone regardless of reputation.

Comment: (By the way, you don't need to delete this answer -- downvotes on Meta do not affect your reputation or your standing in the main site. Also, when a Meta post proposes a feature, like this answer does, downvotes generally mean disagreement with the suggestion, and not that the post is worthy of delention.)

Comment: @duplode Thank you for your comments. Re formatting, I agree with your view, though I was swayed by the example that there can be exceptions where in some limited formatting may be of value. Hence reading through, I came to my suggestion.

Comment: @duplode I also thank you for advising of the negative votes. I dedicatingly participated in another SE group, as acknowledged by a key moderator type person. I was so heavily targeted and redirected with seemingly every post, that I went out backwards. It was in an area of great personal passion and experience.  Each down vote always justified (plausable) but extinguishing of participation or tolerance.

Comment: @duplode The experience above on this other SE group led to writing my first bit of verse in a decade. "Ode to an SE Group". About 3 days work unpicking the experience.  I wrote a long passionate dissection for that groups meta, but never posted the outcome. Could not finish so just ceased participation in that group. Sad. Hence a bit touchy.

Comment: You may also have touched a nerve here. "Privileges", reputation, and how they relate to new users, are frequent topics here on Meta. This is probably due to SO being the flagship site of Stack Exchange, and with an influx of n00bs in the order of [more than 3,000 users per day](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252054) it often feels like fighting windmills.

Comment: You seem to be answering a different thing than what is being asked here. Although the title says "formatting", it doesn't really mean *formatting* — it means *abuse of Unicode to achieve quasi-formatted titles, since actual formatting in titles is not allowed*.

Comment: @RadLexus  Astonishing. Raw nerve touched, appreciate the explanation. Though, this being true, I was raising just such a concern if formatting were to be allowed in questions. Just that concern. n00bs, having been one only a year ago. Cody Gray was also correct in that I did not understand the issue precisely re difference formatting vs changes to Unicode. I also wonder how allowing such would impair or complicate internal search engines, and what people put into them.

Comment: @Code Gray. You are correct I did not understand that difference, even though it was mention on the python main chat when I was there last. Thanks, appreciated. My response to this question was, leave it as it is. I was swayed by anothers point to consider, now I understand better, I agree fully, leave it as it is now.

Comment: Even though I have attracted a  -9 (so far) I do very much appreciate the comments and feedback. Thanks.  Moving on from this discussion.

Comment: I don't think this is a great idea because in a way this allows experienced users (i.e., those who have high rep) to "advertise" their questions by , for example, bolding their question title, while low-rep users (lurkers such as myself) are left behind. Besides, a question title should be self-explanatory enough that formatting should not be necessary anyways (with the only exception being this very meta post).

Comment: @Mage Xy That is a good point as well. Such might be moderated if the threshold for permission was very high perhaps, in that I think those very experienced and committing so much time, love the site too much to resort to such, and would have no need.  In any case, I agree with your view.  I have returned to my initial view, aligned with yours, keep it as it is, no formatting.  Works fine as it is.   The issue, by the way, as explained by Code Gray, is not formatting in the normal sense, eg adding bold text, but rather using altered (hacked?) Unicode. See a few comments up by him.

Comment: @Cam_Aust -there are a lot of mean-spirited coldhearted, even immature people and trolls, even in well-organized technocracies. Not everyone is like that, but anything open-minded, liberal, free thinking, or that expects fair treatment is going to be frowned on immediately by authoritarian sorts here, so, you'd better get used to it. Like in the real world, some people prefer a dictatorship and blind obedience to a monarchy regardless of whether the charter espouses democracy.  A newbie shocked by this is in for an unpleasant surprise. You must shut up and go along to get along or be ridiculed

Comment: @clearlight Stackoverflow seems such a wonderful collaborative effort, I tend to assume such issues have been weeded out as part of the structure. Being fairly new, and learning, in most situations I do not yet have the experience base to judge the behaviour of others and the response, hence I do very much appreciate your comment. The initial response here did feel like a degree of troll behaviour, but perceptions can be wrong. I have felt it on another SE group, pushed out. Let me just say thank you for what was not clear and discernible with certainty from my relativistic position.

Comment: They'll beat the holy *$@! out of you w/neg flags in meta if you don't conform to the collective expectation, or if you're unpopular, or made an innocent mistake, or, just because someone else flagged you. And there are cliques and follow-the-leader.  Definitely not all objectively compassionate or even reasonable. If you're a nobody and you complain about anything with merit not, expect to be heavily down-voted for mentioning it.  Conform. Don't make waves, and you might get the benefit of the doubt. Be contrite and kiss butt. Generally the perspective on meta is more punitive than tolerant.

Comment: @clearlight It seems you have a few bruises yourself.  I have noted with any good work, eg SE, as success is gained, troll like personalities get attracted like flies and parasites, to steel kudos for themselves, and spoil a good thing for others - which seems to give them such a sense of empowerment and achievement.

Comment: @clearlight. Do appreciate the heads up.

Comment: @Cam_Aust - I don't mean to suggest there aren't good or helpful people here. There are some brilliant, fair, egalitarian or at least well-intentioned sorts. I have a LOT of respect for Stack Overflow for many things, but there are some pretty rude Authoritarian trollish types on meta. That's what I believe. I recently posted a question that wasn't damned, finally. Just don't complain or express any anger over anything handed out to you. Otherwise you're doomed.  And don't f' up even a little otherwise they'll pummel you in a big dog pile. Many pretty much like to pick on the underdog.

Comment: @clearlight  Ironically something for a meta discussion. Another issue I sense, is the risk at this stage of SE and SO of burnout at the higher experience levels, with workload created by 'demanding unthinking noobies' (as a significant subcategory of noobies). Both seem relevant at this time.

Comment: @Cam_Aust - that makes sense. I'm sure it's hard to handle too many people dinged at the fringe balking.  2wks ago I was banned for a week from review because I approved a one sentence dry non-creative tag description that the mod found out was plagiarized. There was nothing that overtly prepared me or informed me to check for plagiarism or I would have checked. Even the discussion here recommended 1-day ban on 1st time offenders. But 90% voters & cmt feedback gave me NO deference. That said a lot. One guy said no justice for me because I wasn't contrite about it, regardless of how it started.

Comment: Want to move to chat?