# Title that contains Japanese character doesn't show proper warning

Tags: bug, title, error-message, quality-filter

Mistakenly I was about to post a question in Japanese to `stackoverflow.com` instead of `ja.stackoverflow.com`.

That was prevented by the warning of title that contains not proper string.

> Title cannot contain "".
>
> This appears to be spam. If you feel you've received this message in error, please visit meta.

But as you see there is a small glitch. The warning doesn't show Japanese string. Most probably other non-latin characters have same issues.

Comment: Can you share what the actual character(s) was/were?

Comment: [I think this is by-design](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311004/unable-to-edit-question-containing-non-latin-characters-warning-about-body-can)

Comment: [also related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343700/please-change-the-spam-error-message), but that one is status-completed

Comment: @rene The title was "popup-menuの関数名の最後のアスタリスクについて".

Comment: I think the character set used in [so] is latin for certain things. This can be noticed in profile name field too

Comment: @ironsand You may want to add a screenshot of the error to your question

Comment: @CodyGray so confusing the user (say he didn't notice he's on the Japanese site) and wasting his time until he figures it out/by not knowing what's wrong with his post is by design? If that's the case then I'd call it bad design

Comment: @Ab_ the message actually said "spammers go away", but it was later changed.

Comment: @Ab_ IMHO it's not that hard to notice that you're not on the right site. Especially when you're seeing all text is english instead of japanese ... By design it's okay to show any kind of information that will point you in the right direction which it does.

Comment: @CodyGray Would it be possible to change the error to say something like "Your title contains invalid characters." The current error message looks more like a bug than anything else.

Comment: I would assume the issue is it is a different character set, so it is parsing the string into something else, and the issue it had with your string was because it turned one of the Japanese characters into one(or multiple) characters that don't map to actual visible characters, but the characters used for formatting and such(such as new line, carriage return, end of file, etc.)  Because of this, the invalid character it displays doesn't show up as anything.  It would probably be ideal to write a parser, that changed it from a character to a human friendly string.

Comment: Related: [     ?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342024/215552)

Answer (score 6):

That non-informative error is very much by design.

The  sites are regularly targeted by  spammers. A lot of those post contains content with non-latin characters. As in general the posts here are not supposed to contain a lot of those characters, entering them and then posting leads to an blocking error.

To not educate the non-legit users of internet real-estate the error message is lacking details about which exact characters are tripping that condition.

We rely on the fact that legit users will go seek for further guidance and then end-up on Meta finding the question and this answer.

If you remove all of the non-latin characters from the title and instead describe the type  characters in your title the error would vanish.

It is worth noting that the body of the post has a similar check with the same non-informative error message:

[Unable to edit question containing non-Latin characters, warning about 'Body cannot contain...'](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311004/unable-to-edit-question-containing-non-latin-characters-warning-about-body-can)

Comment: @HereticMonkey said this is mainly a concern of hacked accounts. Are low rep spammers an issue or hacked accounts?

Comment: I didn't say it was mainly anything. That's just a concern of mine regarding high-rep accounts being able to post spam-like titles and posts. I don't think that, just because an account has higher rep, it should be able to get away with posting content that a lower-rep account could not. @andI'msureI'mmissingsome

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue [recently](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402161/title-cant-contain-what).

I think it would be easy enough to check the privileges or reputation of a logged in user like me (~40k at the time of writing) and allow Unicode characters in the title and in the post.

I hope that spammers are detected earlier and will not 200 reputation.

Comment: I disagree. I think all rep levels should be treated the same. If a spammer hacks your account, they shouldn't be able to go on a spam spree just because you have 40k.

Comment: @HereticMonkey: I still think we should tackle hacked accounts on a different level than error messages. It's the wrong tool for the job, IMHO. Other sites require to confirm a "new device", "new browser" or what they call it. Also IMHO, spam will be flagged soon, so why not let me ask 3 spam questions, prevent posting more questions in a short time span and notify me about potential spam misuse by email?