# Title can't contain what?

Tags: bug, error-message

I don't want to post spam and I have no idea what's wrong with that title. It describes axactly my problem, IMHO.

[image: Error message]

I was unable to read what exactly the title may not contain, so I zoomed in a bit:

[image: Error message large]

Ok, the title can't contain double quotation marks - but I don't have that.

Oh! You mean an empty string? Well, my title is not an empty string. Of course it contains a lot of empty strings (in C# at least: `"Hello World".Contains(""))`)

I also assume that backslashes are quite ok on a programming site.

你好 is Chinese for "Hello". 你你 is probably a typo of that, but who cares?

Finally, I figured out it's related to the Chinese characters and I published without them.

Can we have better error messages, please?

Comment: @JohnMontgomery: if there were an answer, it might answer my question, yes. So we have that bug for 3 years already. Great! What's the problem of fixing this?

Comment: Did you use the Contact Us link in the footer as instructed?

Comment: I've written an answer on the duplicate.

Comment: Just write a better title. That title is *too specific*. In the rare event that someone is actually searching for that exact sequence of characters, having them in the body of the question will be sufficient. The more likely case is that someone is having a similar problem, and it is *that* problem which you should attempt to capture in the title. Dumping non-English characters into titles almost never helps anyone.

Comment: "Can we have better error messages, please?" - It won't help you in the end. The best that can probably be done for the given error is "the title does not pass validation". Definitely reads less broken, but it still does not tell you anything you didn't already know.

Comment: @Gimby: "Your title cannot contain these Unicode characters" would have been helpful and saved me a lot of trial and error. And why not mention the affected characters? Shouldn't be too hard. And if it's too hard, the programmers can ask how to do it on SO :-D

Comment: @CodyGray: ok, got it. Other titles ("Why does my Regex not work?") are too broad. Anyway, I'll try harder next time.