# Is the "nearly 2,000 flags per day" statistic in the election page out of date?

Tags: discussion, support, flags, moderation, moderator-election

## tl;dr: How many flags do we *actually* get a day on Stack Overflow?

---

The current, 2019 elections say (emphasis mine):

> Due to the size of Stack Overflow (averaging **nearly 2,000 flags per day!**), moderation can be [a significant responsibility](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287878/1364007) - if you can't dedicate at least 30 minutes each day to help shoulder the load, please defer to those who can.

The linked question is dated August 2011 and says (emphasis mine):

> in the last 30 days as of the time I am writing this, there have been 26,710 flags. That is **890 flags *per day* on average.**

---

I initially wanted to look back through the past elections to see at what rate this number was increasing, but was thwarted by the election page text having been retrospectively made to all be the same - from the [first 2011 elections](https://stackoverflow.com/election/1) to the [current, 2019 elections](https://stackoverflow.com/election/11), even though question linked to in the text

> ...and [cannot have been suspended during the past year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/274114/284827).

is to "[*Let's disallow nominations from people who've been suspended in the past year*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/274114/284827)" (a proposal) dated February 2016 and so **can't** have been in effect (publicly, at least) in the earlier elections.

---

Luckily, [The Internet Archive](http://web.archive.org/) exists so I was able to do some investigation, and found the following:

- The first mirror of the second 2011 moderator elections (captured December 2011 - [link](http://web.archive.org/web/20111225005519/http://stackoverflow.com/election/2)) has *no reference to the number of flags per day*.
- The first mirror of the 2012 moderator elections (captured June 2012 - [link](http://web.archive.org/web/20120610164233/http://stackoverflow.com/election/3)) says

  > Due to the size of Stack Overflow (with an average of over 1,000 flags per day!)
- The first mirror of the 2013 moderator elections (captured March 2013 - [link](http://web.archive.org/web/20130301014628/http://stackoverflow.com/election/4)) says

  > Due to the size of Stack Overflow (averaging nearly 2,000 flags per day!)

Since then the mirrors of the successive elections have said the same thing (about the number of flags per day, at least).

Looking at meta questions like [How many new users does Stack Overflow get per day?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252043/1364007), I found queries on the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) like: [New accounts per day (moving average)](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/269343/new-accounts-per-day-moving-average?MovingAvg=180#graph) which shows that the number of *new* users since 2013 hasn't exactly stayed about the same (I set the moving average to be over 180 days to smooth out anomalies):

[image: New accounts per day, 180-day moving average]

I fully get that lots of users register, ask one question, then their account is neglected afterwards, but I would have thought that the number of active users, and therefore the number of flags per day, has also increased since 2013?

Is there some fault in my logic, and/or is the "*nearly 2,000 flags per day*" statistic wrong?

Comment: I expect a lot of the flags to be close flags, which are not flags requiring moderator action. If that statistic is to be updated, could it be specified if it's _nearly 2000 flags requiring moderator intervention_ or _nearly 2000, but 70% of that is close flags by <2K users so actually more like 600 flags per day_

Comment: Insider info: we've got 16,000 flags in the past week ... so that is around 2.3k~ ... it goes up to 3k on Wednesdays and slips to 700~800 on the weekends.. It _is_ still accurate, and would perhaps be shifted to 3k, once we cross getting 2.5k~ per day on an average.

Comment: Yes, I hadn't considered close flags. If the close flags are included in the statistics, then it'd be odd to include them there. When I read it, I had assumed that to be actual moderator flags which 'normal' users will never see. Clarification would be nice.

Comment: @BhargavRao is that moderator-only flags, or are other flags (like NAA, VLQ, spam, rude/abusive flags) that are also dealt with by the community included too?

Comment: NAA, VLQ are moderator flags too! Spam, R/A aren't. Moderator flags are the custom flags, NAA/VLQ, comment flags and the numerous automatic flags.

Comment: @WaiHaLee just to note - the previous versions of the election pages are available - see: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8041931/revisions

Comment: @BhargavRao - huh - okay: I'd have thought that spam and R/A would moderator flags be as they potentially cause the most damage and should be dealt with the soonest.

Comment: @JonClements oh, I see - I hadn't expected the election page to be another post - that explains why they're all the same.

Comment: @WaiHaLee if it wasn't for the fact I can see a link for the history on it and that I knew from a while back it's in SEDE - I wouldn't have guessed that either :)

Comment: @WaiHaLee: we are 10 hours into the UTC day and moderators have directly handled more than 400 flags. We'll easily have handled over 1000 by the end of it. Not all flags we handle show up in that count; if I see a spam flag in the queue and agree by flagging it a spam too, it is Community that then deletes the post and gains a +1 on the flags handled counter, not me.

Comment: @WaiHaLee: also, comment flags on a post count as '1' flag handled. Someone flagging 25 comments to delete is counted the same as a single 'please delete the comments' custom moderator flag in that respect. All in all, there are a lot of different ways to slice and dice the flag stats. The 2k count is a decent middle ground.

Comment: different perspective: in the past 30 days, the top 5 most prolific flag-handling moderators handled 11.3k, 6k, 3.6k, 3.1k and 2k flags, respectively. But not all flags are equal, cleaning up an account that has plagiarised about 60% of their 5000 answers takes a lot more time than cleaning up 'thank you, it works!' comments.

Comment: And finally: chat flags are nowhere to be found in any of these statistics. Some moderators do a lot of chat moderating, but we have no stats for that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'd be very interested to see breakdowns based on "work hours" per day instead of flags per day. As you said, some flags require a couple seconds of deliberation while some can involve half an hour or more of sleuthing. Are any such stats recorded?

Comment: @Magisch: no, that's impossible to record. When I'm active, I could be answering questions, while at the same time cleaning out comment flags in the background or figuring out if a piece of Android XML and Java code is plagiarised or original work, all at the same time.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Was there really someone plagiarizing 60% of their 5000 answers?

Comment: Since the increasing number of flags has been raised I feel somewhat compelled to mention my own feature-request from 2014: "[Could high-rep users help with clearing comment flags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278927/could-high-rep-users-help-with-clearing-comment-flags)" for further review.

Comment: @justhalf those numbers were made up for illustration, but I’ve certainly cleaned out plagiarism counting in the hundreds of posts for a single account. I don’t keep stats however.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - wow, that was more stats than I expected to get: thank you for the extra insight.

Comment: @BhargavRao - I just re-read your comment. You said that it's about 2.3k/day over the last week (which I assume is representative of most other weeks). In that case, shouldn't (at least) the "nearly" in "*nearly 2,000 flags per day*" be changed?

Comment: @WaiHaLee, it is still nearly 2000 if you round down. ;p ... but yeah, it does makes sense to put it at "more than 2000".

Comment: Note however that there's a kind of "hard" plateau from which the system doesn't handle well more questions. Questions are the main drive of flags, since they are the start of every activity on the site, like answers and comments.

Comment: I can see that it is possible to manipulate the post link, in the same way as any other post, to edit it. I guess I *could* edit it myself (I assume my >2k reputation means that it'd skip the queue and go straight through), but I wouldn't dare to mess with it unless specifically given some kind of approval. :/

Comment: All of the chatroom links, daily flag count and the Q&A thread links are the same on all election pages with the links pointing to the latest election Q&A or chatroom.

Comment: @smileycreations15 - that's because they're all the same [post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8041931/revisions).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Let's have a look at [2018: a year in moderation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378415/2018-a-year-in-moderation)...

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Questions flagged                             1,453    592,454
Question flags handled                       38,092    555,815
Comments flagged                              1,634    345,828
Comment flags handled                       211,510    135,952
Answers flagged                               3,504    462,254
Answer flags handled                        219,741    246,017
```

If we add up *all* the flags raised, we get 1,408,127 flags - or an average of about 3,857 flags per day. Clearly that's somewhat more than 2,000...

However, that includes flags *raised by* moderators, as well as flags that were handled by the system or by members of the community - and there are a lot of those! So let's add up the flags handled *by moderators* instead:

```
38,092+211,510+219,741=469,343
```

...or about 1285 per day. And that's significantly *lower* than 2,000!

But, it still doesn't give us the full picture. Some flags age away if not handled; others *must* be handled - if not handled by the community via /review, then by moderators. And the volume of flags varies considerably over time - both by day of the week, and by time of year.

So I looked up the number of flags *excluding close flags* raised per day over the course of 2018, and calculated the first quartile (969), median (1,646), and 3rd quartile (1808).

With all this in mind, I think it's probably best to say that the moderator team should be *prepared to handle* nearly 2,000 flags per day... Even though the average number of flags *raised* is much higher, and the average number of flags that must be handled by the moderators is much lower.

To satisfy your curiosity for how this has changed over time, here's a funky-looking box-plot showing the distribution for each year since 2010:

[image]

#### Footnote

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1).

Comment: Can you please explain why older election pages were retroactively edited?

Comment: @gparyani - they are all [a single post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8041931/revisions) so edits apply to all elections - see comments above: [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380904/is-the-nearly-2-000-flags-per-day-statistic-in-the-election-page-out-of-date/381074#comment675018_380904), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380904/is-the-nearly-2-000-flags-per-day-statistic-in-the-election-page-out-of-date/381074#comment675021_380904).